# How to increase Databricks performance?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a problem here that I write to synapse running taking so much time (> 20 hours). What can I do to improving my Databricks that need to write to synapse? My resource table is from Fact Table (Contains 151 millions of row) on Azure Synase. I assumming that my script is not good to running on Databricks, and also I assuming that it was caused by Garbage Collection that made my job stuck. However, how can I solving this problem to prevent that running in a long time into fastest time?

This is my script, it was group by CUBE:

```py
cube_department_read = cube_department_df.cube(cube_department_df["YEAR"], cube_department_df["WeekOfYear"], cube_department_df["Month"], 
                                cube_department_df["department_groups"], cube_department_df["category_name"], 
                                cube_department_df["subcategory_name"], cube_department_df["section_name"]) \
        .agg(F.max('last_date_of_week').alias('last_date_of_week'), 
             F.countDistinct('internal_tranx_key').alias('sales_basket'), 
             F.sum('SalesAmt').alias('sales_amt'), 
             F.sum('SalesQty').alias('sales_qty'),
             F.sum('SalesQtyPro').alias('SalesQtyPro'), 
             F.sum('SalesAmtPro').alias('SalesAmtPro'),
             F.countDistinct('membership_id').alias('member_count'),
             F.sum(F.when(cube_department_df["membership_id"].isNotNull(), 
                        cube_department_df["SalesQty"]).otherwise(0)).alias("SalesQty_Member"),
             F.sum(F.when(cube_department_df["membership_id"].isNotNull(), 
                        cube_department_df["SalesAmt"]).otherwise(0)).alias("SalesAmt_Member"),
             F.sum(F.when(cube_department_df["membership_id"].isNotNull(), 
                        1).otherwise(0)).alias("Basket_Count_Member"),
             F.sum(F.when(cube_department_df["membership_id"].isNotNull(), 
                        0).otherwise(cube_department_df["SalesQty"])).alias("SalesQty_NonMember"),
             F.sum(F.when(cube_department_df["membership_id"].isNotNull(), 
                        0).otherwise(cube_department_df["SalesAmt"])).alias("SalesAmt_NonMember"),
             F.sum(F.when(cube_department_df["membership_id"].isNotNull(), 
                        0).otherwise(1)).alias("Basket_Count_NonMember"),
             F.sum(F.when(cube_department_df["promotion_flag"] == 'Y', 
                        cube_department_df["SalesAmt"]).otherwise(0)).alias("SalesAmt_MMDS_Promotion"),
             F.sum(F.when(cube_department_df["promotion_flag"] == 'Y', 
                        cube_department_df["SalesQty"]).otherwise(0)).alias("SalesQty_MMDS_Promotion"),
             F.sum(F.when(cube_department_df["promotion_flag"] == 'Y', 
                        1).otherwise(0)).alias("Basket_Count_MMDS_Promotion"),
             F.sum(F.when(cube_department_df["promotion_flag"] == 'Y', 
                        0).otherwise(cube_department_df["SalesAmt"])).alias("SalesAmt_Non_MMDS_Promotion"),
             F.sum(F.when(cube_department_df["promotion_flag"] == 'Y', 
                        0).otherwise(cube_department_df["SalesQty"])).alias("SalesQty_Non_MMDS_Promotion"),
             F.sum(F.when(cube_department_df["promotion_flag"] == 'Y', 
                        0).otherwise(1)).alias("Basket_Count_Non_MMDS_Promotion"),
             F.sum(F.when((cube_department_df["promotion_flag"] == 'Y') & (cube_department_df["membership_id"].isNotNull()), 
                        cube_department_df["SalesAmt"]).otherwise(0)).alias("SalesAmt_Member_MMDS_Promotion"),
             F.sum(F.when((cube_department_df["promotion_flag"] == 'Y') & (cube_department_df["membership_id"].isNotNull()), 
                        cube_department_df["SalesQty"]).otherwise(0)).alias("SalesQty_Member_MMDS_Promotion"),
             F.sum(F.when((cube_department_df["promotion_flag"] == 'Y') & (cube_department_df["membership_id"].isNotNull()), 
                        1).otherwise(0)).alias("Basket_Count_Member_MMDS_Promotion"),
             F.sum(F.when((cube_department_df["promotion_flag"] == 'Y') & (cube_department_df["membership_id"].isNull()), 
                        cube_department_df["SalesAmt"]).otherwise(0)).alias("SalesAmt_Non_Member_MMDS_Promotion"),
             F.sum(F.when((cube_department_df["promotion_flag"] == 'Y') & (cube_department_df["membership_id"].isNull()), 
                        cube_department_df["SalesQty"]).otherwise(0)).alias("SalesQty_Non_Member_MMDS_Promotion"),
             F.sum(F.when((cube_department_df["promotion_flag"] == 'Y') & (cube_department_df["membership_id"].isNull()), 
                        1).otherwise(0)).alias("Basket_Count_Non_Member_MMDS_Promotion"),
             F.sum(F.when((cube_department_df["promotion_flag"] == 'N') & (cube_department_df["membership_id"].isNotNull()), 
                        cube_department_df["SalesAmt"]).otherwise(0)).alias("SalesAmt_Member_Non_MMDS_Promotion"),
             F.sum(F.when((cube_department_df["promotion_flag"] == 'N') & (cube_department_df["membership_id"].isNotNull()), 
                        cube_department_df["SalesQty"]).otherwise(0)).alias("SalesQty_Member_Non_MMDS_Promotion"),
             F.sum(F.when((cube_department_df["promotion_flag"] == 'N') & (cube_department_df["membership_id"].isNotNull()), 
                        1).otherwise(0)).alias("Basket_Count_Member_Non_MMDS_Promotion"),
             F.sum(F.when((cube_department_df["promotion_flag"] == 'N') & (cube_department_df["membership_id"].isNull()), 
                        cube_department_df["SalesAmt"]).otherwise(0)).alias("SalesAmt_Non_Member_Non_MMDS_Promotion"),
             F.sum(F.when((cube_department_df["promotion_flag"] == 'N') & (cube_department_df["membership_id"].isNull()), 
                        cube_department_df["SalesQty"]).otherwise(0)).alias("SalesQty_Non_Member_Non_MMDS_Promotion"),
             F.sum(F.when((cube_department_df["promotion_flag"] == 'N') & (cube_department_df["membership_id"].isNull()), 
                        1).otherwise(0)).alias("Basket_Count_Non_Member_Non_MMDS_Promotion"),
            F.when((F.sum(cube_department_df["SalesQty"]) < 0) & (F.sum(cube_department_df["SalesAmt"]) < 0),
                (F.sum(cube_department_df["SalesAmt"]) / F.sum(cube_department_df["SalesQty"])) * -1) \
                .when((F.sum(cube_department_df["SalesQty"]) == 0) | (F.sum(cube_department_df["SalesAmt"]) == 0),
                0).otherwise(F.sum(cube_department_df["SalesAmt"]) / F.sum(cube_department_df["SalesQty"])).alias("sales_per_unit"),
            F.when((F.sum(cube_department_df["SalesQty"]) < 0) & (F.sum(cube_department_df["SalesAmt"]) < 0),
                (F.sum(cube_department_df["SalesAmt"]) / F.countDistinct(cube_department_df["internal_tranx_key"])) * -1) \
                .when((F.sum(cube_department_df["SalesQty"]) == 0) | (F.sum(cube_department_df["SalesAmt"]) == 0),
                0).otherwise(F.sum(cube_department_df["SalesAmt"]) / F.countDistinct(cube_department_df["internal_tranx_key"])).alias("sales_per_basket"),
            F.when((F.sum(cube_department_df["SalesQty"]) < 0) & (F.sum(cube_department_df["SalesAmt"]) < 0),
                (F.sum(cube_department_df["SalesQty"]) / F.countDistinct(cube_department_df["internal_tranx_key"])) * -1) \
                .when((F.sum(cube_department_df["SalesQty"]) == 0) | (F.sum(cube_department_df["SalesAmt"]) == 0),
                0).otherwise(F.sum(cube_department_df["SalesQty"]) / F.countDistinct(cube_department_df["internal_tranx_key"])).alias("unit_per_basket"),    
            F.when((F.countDistinct(cube_department_df["membership_id"]) < 0) & (F.sum(cube_department_df["SalesAmt"]) < 0),
                (F.sum(cube_department_df["SalesAmt"]) / F.countDistinct(cube_department_df["membership_id"])) * -1) \
                .when((F.countDistinct(cube_department_df["membership_id"]) == 0) | (F.sum(cube_department_df["SalesAmt"]) == 0),
                0).otherwise(F.sum(cube_department_df["SalesAmt"]) / F.countDistinct(cube_department_df["membership_id"])).alias("spend_per_customer")) \
        .select("YEAR","WeekOfYear","Month","department_groups","category_name","subcategory_name","section_name",
                "last_date_of_week","sales_basket","sales_amt","sales_qty","SalesQtyPro","SalesAmtPro",
                "member_count","SalesQty_Member","SalesAmt_Member", "Basket_Count_Member",
                "SalesQty_NonMember","SalesAmt_NonMember", "Basket_Count_NonMember", 
                "SalesAmt_MMDS_Promotion", "SalesQty_MMDS_Promotion", "Basket_Count_MMDS_Promotion",
                "SalesAmt_Non_MMDS_Promotion","SalesQty_Non_MMDS_Promotion", "Basket_Count_Non_MMDS_Promotion",
                "SalesAmt_Member_MMDS_Promotion","SalesQty_Member_MMDS_Promotion","Basket_Count_Member_MMDS_Promotion",
                "SalesAmt_Non_Member_MMDS_Promotion","SalesQty_Non_Member_MMDS_Promotion","Basket_Count_Non_Member_MMDS_Promotion",
                "SalesAmt_Member_Non_MMDS_Promotion","SalesQty_Member_Non_MMDS_Promotion","Basket_Count_Member_Non_MMDS_Promotion",
               "SalesAmt_Non_Member_Non_MMDS_Promotion","SalesQty_Non_Member_Non_MMDS_Promotion","Basket_Count_Non_Member_Non_MMDS_Promotion",
                "sales_per_unit","sales_per_basket","unit_per_basket", "spend_per_customer") \
        .orderBy(F.col("YEAR").asc(), 
           F.col("WeekOfYear").asc(), 
           F.col("Month").asc(),
           F.col("department_groups").asc(), 
           F.col("category_name").asc(),
           F.col("subcategory_name").asc(), 
           F.col("section_name").asc())
```

This is my Garbage Collection
[image]

So, what can I do from here? I have a Fact table resource that contains 151 million of rows. I'm sorry, I'm new on Databricks, because I need to do the CUBE script, on Synapse CUBE is not supported yet, so I need to do this CUBE on databricks.

Answer (score 0):

The slowest part of writing from Databricks to Synapse is in the step where Databricks writes to the temporary directory (Azure Blob Storage).

Databricks -> Blob Store is not handled by Polybase. Only the Blob Store -> Synapse/Azure DW is Polybase, and that part usually moves quickly.

You can try to change the write semantics: [Databricks documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/azure/synapse-analytics.html#write-semantics)

Using the copy write semantics, you will be able to load data in Synapse faster.

You can configure it before running the write command, in this way:

`spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.sqldw.writeSemantics", "copy")`

Comment: I have tried this configuration, but nothing happened, same as before, write slowly. Is there any way to do with the performance on databricks? I had tried using write to delta to my blob storage, but the performance same as write to synapse, very-very-low

Comment: I request you to raise a support for synapse write issue. For blob, I'll try to provide any solution if I get.

Comment: I think this is more of a performance issue with the `cube` function rather than persisting data to a file system. The `cube` function will generate rows for all possible combinations. `explode` is also a function that generates rows which in some circumstances can be extremely inefficient